# How to shuffle and play an audio file from an array

Tags: java, arrays, audio, actionlistener, shuffle

I have some problems with my code, I want to shuffle a file array that contains .mp3 audio files and play one file from it when a button is clicked!! I absolutely have no Idea on how to do this, I need some help, real help!!  Here is my code!..... It runs but it plays all files at once.... I want it to randomize, and play just one out of the files.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;

public class Quest1 extends JFrame {

    String word [] = { "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/audio.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/baby.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/board.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/bomb.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/gym.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/football.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/school.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/keyboard.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/computer.wav",
            "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/eclipse/name.wav"  };


    JButton click;      

    public Quest1 () {

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();


        g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        g.gridx = 4;
        g.gridy = 5;
        g.gridwidth = 2;
        g.insets = new Insets (50, 2, 2, 2);
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        fill = new JTextField(15);
        add (fill, g);

        g.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        g.gridx = 4;
        g.gridy = 8;
        g.gridwidth = 2;
        g.insets = new Insets (30, 2,2,2);
        click = new JButton("Play");
        add(click, g);

        click.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent x) {

                Random rand = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < word.length;) {
                        int random = rand.nextInt(word.length);
                        String temp = word[i];
                        word [i] = word[random];
                        word[random] = temp;

                        InputStream in =null;
                        AudioStream out = null;
                            try {
                                in = new FileInputStream(temp);
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                out = new AudioStream(in);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }       
                            AudioPlayer.player.start(out);
                    }       
                    return;
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your issue playing the sound files at all, or crafting/selecting from the array?

Comment: Selecting from the array, yes, that's my problem..... I want to randomize, then play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a normal java array holding the files you want to play, the easiest approach is to simply generate a random index and get object with that index from the array:

```
//Index of the random song
int r = (int) (Math.random() * (songs.length - 1);
//Get the song from the array
songs[r]
...
```

**Edit:**

You said you want to play ONE random sound from the array, by know your code just plays ALL of your files in the array in the correct order.

If you only want to play ONE, than you have to remove the `for` loop.

**Correct code:**

```
click.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent x) {
            //Get random filepath from the array
            Random rand = new Random();
            int random = rand.nextInt(word.length);
            String temp = word[random];

            InputStream in =null;
            AudioStream out = null;
            //Get the actual file from the path
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(temp);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                out = new AudioStream(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            //Play the file
            AudioPlayer.player.start(out);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I don't know if you can help me write the syntax for playing the sound file as well, I don't seem to get it straight....... Thanks!

Comment: I need more information in order to help you with playing the file itself.

Comment: I've Edited my post.

Comment: No problem @Presh_K7 :)